# CS50: PSET 3: Binary Search inconsistent success with test data

Tags: c, search, binary, cs50

Can any expert look at this for me?  It's only passing on 2/3rds of the test scenarios - just inconsistent enough to be a complete PIA.  I've spent 10s of hours on it.  Any pointers would be gratefully received.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {

int top = n - 1;
int bottom = 0;
    while (top - bottom >= 0){
        int searchpos = (top - bottom) /2;
        if (value == values[searchpos]){
                return true;
        }

        else if (value > values[searchpos]) {
            bottom = bottom + searchpos + 1;
        } 

        else if (value < values[searchpos]) {
            top = searchpos - 1;
        }

    }      
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate to ask on the CS50 site: http://cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you made sure that the data is sorted?  The asymmetry between `bottom = bottom + searchpos + 1;` and `top = searchpos - 1;` is worrying.  Why aren't they more similar?  Perhaps `bottom = searchpos + 1;`?

Comment: Also, the condition `while (top - bottom >= 0)` would be better expressed as `while (top >= bottom)`.  And finally, you should probably use: `int searchpos = bottom + (top - bottom) / 2;` (or the almost equivalent `int searchpos = (bottom + top) / 2;` — but note the bug that Google ran into, reported at [Extra, Extra, Read All About It!](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).  OTOH, you're unlikely to be dealing with big enough data sets for that to be an actual problem.)